# Custom event not appearing in Gluon SceneBuilder 'code' panel

Tags: scala, events, javafx, scenebuilder

Are custom event handlers for custom controls meant to show up in the ScenBuilder 'code' panel?

My custom control, C , fires a custom action event, E:

```
class E (val data: ... ) extends ActionEvent 

class C { ...

    type Handler = EventHandler[E]

    def getOnE            : Handler          = onE.get()
    def setOnE(h: Handler): Unit             = onE.set(handler)
    def onEProperty       : ObjectProperty[Handler] = onE       
    val onE = new SimpleObjectProperty(this,"E")
    ...
}
```

I build my jar, point SceneBuilder at it via the 'JAR/FXML Manager' dialog, and the control appears and works within SceneBuilder just fine. Wiring up an instance of the control to invoke the onE handler of a controller by editing the FXML file directly works fine too:

...but I was hoping for the 'onE' handler to appear in SceneBuilder's 'code' panel like all the other predefined event handler properties. Have i done something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

it appears that there is a bug with the latest release of scenebuilder (8.4.0).

It is already reported as bug https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/scenebuilder/issues/147/missing-code-section#comment-40272722

You can downgrade to 8.3.0 that will probably solve your issue

Comment: thanks, but unfortunately it does not - i am already using 8.3.0.

Comment: More generally, should I expect other properties of my custom control - eg. some String property i decide to expose - to also appear editable within the scenebuilder automagically?